# Modifying DataTable with multiple foreach loops

Tags: c#, foreach

First thanks for taking the time to help if you can, now to the question. I am modifying an existing Data table to get a desired output.

I have written the code already to either do nothing, delete, or add column/row data. I viewed the Data table using dataset result viewer and it comes out as desired. But here in lies the problem, the data rows and data column's are in foreach loops, and I am now getting "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute.".

I did everything in one Data Table, unaware that it would make the table immutable or un-modifiable if that is the correct term. I copied the table, and in a for loop, tried to iterate through it backwards as a suggestion from StackOverflow. But it did not work. So, I think I might have to either make a new method and create a new data Table within it, then set the columns, instantiate the Data Table and loop through the original table. Then add the rows to the new table and return that table.

But I am lost on how to even begin this process, I am a bit puzzled on what is the best way to do so and could use some advice. Here is My code if it helps out. I have a lot of small extension methods I am using to do the bulk of the work. Thank you for any advice on the matter!

```
internal void ParseNames(DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ConvertExcelToDataTable != null && ConvertExcelToDataTable.Rows != null)
            {
                foreach(DataRow dr in ConvertExcelToDataTable.Select())
                {
                    foreach(DataColumn col in ConvertExcelToDataTable.Columns)
                    {
                            ConvertExcelToDataTable.AcceptChanges(); //initial DataTable Save
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("LOB");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("UMID");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("MBR_SEX");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("DOS");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("Measures");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("ProjectName");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("Project Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("MemberKey");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("MSR_KEY");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("PRV_LAST");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("PRV_FIRST");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("PRV_MI");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("LocationName");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("Request ID");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("Measure(s)");
                            dr.Table.Columns.ReplaceItem("", "3");
                            dr.Table.Columns.ReplaceItem(" ", "3");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("PERS_FIRST_NAME", "First_Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("FirstName", "First_Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("MBR_FIRST", "First_Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("MBR_LAST", "Last_Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("LastName", "Last_Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("Gender", "Gender");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("MBR_SEX", "Gender");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("PERS_MID_INIT", "Middle_Initial");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("MBR_MI", "Middle_Initial");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("BIRTHDATE", "Date_of_Birth");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("PatientDOB", "Date_of_Birth");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("DOB", "Date_of_Birth");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveSpecialCharacters("(");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveSpecialCharacters(")");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveSpecialCharacters(",");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveSpecialCharacters("=");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveSpecialCharacters("!");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveSpecialCharacters("-");
                            dr.Table.Columns.SplitPatientData("Patient Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.SplitPatientData("PatientName");
                            dr.Table.Columns.SplitPatientData("Patient, Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("Patient", "First_Name");
                            dr.Table.Columns.RenamingColumnValue("Name", "Last_Name");
                            SplitPatientRowData(ConvertExcelToDataTable);
                            dr.Table.Columns.RemoveItem("Patient Name");
                            ReverseRowsInDataTable(ConvertExcelToDataTable);
                            ConvertExcelToDataTable.AcceptChanges();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Removing columns while iterating columns - is going to blow up; but I'm not sure why you would be manipulating the *column* data *at all*? Shouldn't you be editing the *row* data?

Comment: I can see any utility of this loop  `foreach(DataColumn col in ConvertExcelToDataTable.Columns)` , what you do here is processing `DataRows` , with `foreach` you will get exception because it not allowed to modify the collection during the loop.

Comment: Correct, I am removing Row Data, I apologize for the confusion. Some Columns are being removed due to them not being a common field needed in the new table. And @Badro that was my issue! It failed when going through the foreach loop col. Man I feel silly, I really appreciate you all taking the time to answer me. Thank you!

Comment: When removing items from a collection (rows) you need to start at last row and move to first using an index like for(int i = Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is basically converting `DataTable` into another `DataTable`. Instead of modifying the existing one in place you can create a new `DataTable` and return it from the method. This way you won't be modifying the DataTable while iterating.

```
internal DataTable ParseNames(DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable)
{
    if (ConvertExcelToDataTable == null && ConvertExcelToDataTable.Rows == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var output = new DataTable();
    // Add columns here

    try
    {

       foreach(DataRow dr in ConvertExcelToDataTable.Select())
       {
           // Add rows here
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    return output;
}
```